# Read Java System.out output with JavaScript and return it

Tags: javascript, java

Let's say I have a Java code like this running:

```
class SayHello extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 5000);
```

My question: How to read that output with a running JavaScript code, process it, output something and read that back in the Java code?

I tried this to get Java's output and return it back, but it's not printing anything.

My code in `TestCmd.js`:

```
function processTextStream() {
    while (true) {
        line = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll();
        WScript.Echo(line);
    }
}
processTextStream();
```

I run it with `cscript TestCmd.js` but I'm open to alternatives.

Comment: If you are looking for other alternatives, you can do that with shelljs.

Comment: Are you using an applet?

Comment: @PeterRader No, just the windows command line and Netbeans to compile Java files and as an Editor